# Custom headings in a site FAQ: good, bad or "it depends"?

Tags: discussion

We've been having a discussion on bh.se about changes to the [faq](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/faq) and one of the suggestions has been to add ## headers to get extra top level header formatting. I've since discovered that this has been done on several sites (eg [prog.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions): "What about subjective questions?" and [christianity.se](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq): "Who are considered Christians here?", "Can I use comments to discuss the topic of a post?").

The slight technical downside is that although the headings appear in the sidebar as links, they all link to the entire "What kind of questions can I ask here?" section.

I can see the benefit of being able to separate out different kinds of FAQ information under headings, but I'm not sure about taking advantage of a work-around to achieve this, because:

1. the faq is supposed to be simple so perhaps being forced under a single heading is good discipline for keeping it short
2. the idea of using a 'slightly broken' technique makes me uneasy: if we *really* need extra headings shouldn't that be achieved with a feature request and persuading SE of the need instead?

So, are using custom ## headings in a site FAQ a good idea or bad idea, or is that just something each site needs to decide for itself?

Comment: My vote is "let each site decide for itself," as the site will have a general attitude about it anyways and the FAQ will reflect that energy.